# Parts of XeLaTeX doesn't work after moving to LinuxMint

Tags: xetex, compiling, mathspec

I one of my headerfiles, I used the command `\setmathfont[]{XITS Math}`, once I tried to compile the document as always with `xelatex`, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.87 \setmathsfont
                  []{XITS Math}
```

Also, for some reason, XeLaTeX seems to hang when I comment out that line.

This may or may not be relevant:

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 49.1 [with modifications for XeTeX]
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.7; using 1.2.7
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.4.9; using 2.4.9
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.9.0; using 2.9.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.2.49; using 1.2.49
Compiled with poppler version 0.18.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a typo, you wrote `\setmathfont` ... but the logfile clearly shows that you typed `\setmathsfont` mark the extra "s".